# linphone-iphone auto answer

Tags: xcode6, linphone

I am working on linphone-iphone. I have also worked on linphone-android and I found a way to enable autoanswer but for Linphone-iphone I couldnt find it. Please help me. How I can enable auto answer in linphone-iphone. I am using xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Linphone dev here.

You can't enable auto answer on linphone-iphone because the iOS API forbids that you open the mic and video if the linphone app is not the front-facing app.

So you could have the auto answer feature, but that means leaving the screen on all the time, with linphone as the foreground app.